# How to apply css to parent element when child focused in Mui V5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As a simple demonstration, I made this [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/can-parent-know-child-focuses-sofq-material-demo-forked-cueqt?file=/demo.js).
I want to apply some styles to the Box component when the Text field is focused.
In my use case, I can apply styles in the text field's class instant of the parent box.
But I wonder how parent box knows a child is focused or not then apply css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to handle the `onFocus` and `onBlur` event of the text field, and then add additional props to the parent element when the text box is focused.

```
export default function FullWidthTextField() {
  const [textFieldFocused, setTextFieldFocused] = React.useState(false);

  const extraProps = textFieldFocused
    ? { backgroundColor: "orange" } 
    : {};

  const sx = {
    // ... default styles for the box
    ...extraProps
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={sx}>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="fullWidth"
        id="fullWidth"
        onFocus={() => setTextFieldFocused(true)}
        onBlur={() => setTextFieldFocused(false)}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[Here's an updated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/can-parent-know-child-focuses-sofq-material-demo-forked-1rt7s?file=/demo.js:0-684) showing this solution in action.

Comment: Waww. My mistake was searching all things in mui docs and css. I missed something fundamental react and html. This gives me new approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `onFocus` event and `onBlur` events

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function FullWidthTextField() {
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setFocus(!focus);

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    toggle();
  };

  const handleOnblur = () => {
    toggle();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(focus);
  }, [focus]);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: focus ? "80%" : "10%",
        padding: 2,
        margin: 2,
        transition: "width 1s ease-in-out",
        // boxShadow: 3
        boxShadow: 21
      }}
    >
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="fullWidth"
        id="fullWidth"
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        onBlur={handleOnblur}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

You can try out the demo here: [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/can-parent-know-child-focuses-sofq-material-demo-forked-sbjvl?file=/demo.js:0-771)

Comment: I get used to using onClick and forgot other events. =) I was heavily searching on Mui docs. Thank you for the answer. It made me refresh.

Comment: @1t1e1 no problem :) could you evaluate answer (⬆️ or ⬇️) if it was useful for you? Ty